# Как правильно записать +, - в выражении if( znak === +)?

Tags: javascript

```js
function doMath(x, znak, y) {
    x = +prompt("Введите первое число");
    y = +prompt("Введите второе число");
    znak = +prompt("Введите операцию +, -, *, /, %, ^ ");
    let result;

    if (znak === +) {
        result = x + y;
    }

    if (znak === -) {
        result = x - y;
    }

    if (znak === *) {
        result = x * y;
    }

    if (znak === /) {
        result = x / y;
    }

    if (znak === %) {
        result = x % y;
    }

    return result;
}

let functionResult = doMath();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В кавычках:

```
if (znak === "+") {
```

Еще выношу из каментов:

Всю конструкцию лучше заменить на `switch(znak)` и убрать `+` перед prompt, потому что знак это не число.

Comment: еще бы не мешало на `switch` заменить

Answer (score 0):

```js
function doMath(x, znak, y) {
    x = +prompt("Введите первое число");
    y = +prompt("Введите второе число");
    znak = prompt("Введите операцию +, -, *, /, %, ^ ");
    let result;

    switch (znak) {
        case "+":
            result = x + y;
            break;
        case "-":
            result = x - y;
            break;
        case "*":
            result = x * y;
            break;
        case "/":
            result = x / y;
            break;  
        case "%":
            result = x % y;
            break;
        case "^":
            result = Math.pow(x,y);
            break;    
    }

    return result;
}

let functionResult = doMath();
console.log(functionResult);
```